# Prevent removing ItemStyle.xsl when retracting solution

Tags: xslt, versioning, solution-deployment

I'm working on a solution which requires me to override the default ItemStyle.xsl as well as the ContentQueryMain.xsl files.

What I'm interested in knowing is; is there a way to prevent the files from being removed when I retract the solution again?

Can I somehow add them through my WSP deploy but in a way which uses SharePoint versioning so all CQWPs don't throw errors if the solution is one day removed?

Comment: Have you tried deploying the files using a Module? The solution retract shouldn't remove the files provisioned using a module unless you have a event receiver that's deleting them.

Comment: I am deploying using a module, and the xsl files are removed when I deactivate the feature which adds them.

Comment: Try creating a new solution and add one xsl file to the module. See if it deletes the file on feature deactivation/solution retract.

Create a new Module named 'Style Library', add your CustomItemStyle.xsl

Your elements.xml should look like this:
 <Module Name="Style Library" Url="Style Library" RootWebOnly="True">
    <File Path="Style Library\CustomItemStyle.xsl" Url="CustomItemStyle.xsl" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>